# CSS drop down menu with two columns issue

Tags: html, css

I've made a menu, but it's giving me some issues. For some reason in my Fiddle the two columns aren't displaying properly on the first menu, and on the second menu the background color is uneven. There's also an issue with the words overflowing if they're too long. Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/001u1n48/1/

```
<div id="navbar">
   <ul id="dropdown">
      <li class="topnav"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
     <ul>
        <div class="column">
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 6</a></li>
        </div>
     </ul>
     <li class="topnav"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
     <ul>
        <div class="column">
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1asdfasdf</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3fadsfasdfasdfasdfasdf</a></li>
        </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Please add fiddle link here?

Comment: You need to start putting units to those values. Also, having those column divs inside ul tags is not a standard (and buggy), inspect that.

Answer (score 1):

## [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/001u1n48/2/).

Change the `width:50%` to `width:100%` and if you want tow column be located in one line of `Meun 1`. You should merge the two column of `Menu 1`.

```
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 1 1 1 1;
    width:100%;
}
```